# Graphhopper Demo Apk Error

Tags: android, graphhopper

I'm a newbie with maps & routing. I'm running the demo apk on my device Huawei Ascend g610 and  on a Sony Xperia ZL but in both of them the app shows a message saying: "To get downloadable areas restart when connected to the internet. Problem while fetching remote area list: http://graphhopper.com/public/maps/0.3/" so the application doesn't show anything else than the list views Local and Remote and I am actually connected to internet. Did I miss anything before installing the apk?

Thanks in advice

Comment: `http://graphhopper.com/public/maps/0.3/` is returning a 404/not found error, looks like there are only `0.1` and `0.2` publicly-available folders. Either the apk is wrong, or they haven't put up a version `0.3` that can be reached over the internet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried also 0.2 apk and it shows the same error: "To get downloadable areas restart when connected to the internet. Problem while fetching remote area list: http://graphhopper.com/public/maps/0.2/"

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this. Please confirm that it works.

**Update**: Should work since final release of [0.3](http://graphhopper.com/#community).

Comment: Good Guy Graphhopper dev moonlighting as a SO user.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar "Not working" is not helping both of us. What Android version you use, which GraphHopper version and what are the logs telling?

Comment: @Karussell I'm getting the same error. To get downloadable areas restart when connected to the internet. Problem while fetching remote area list: http://graphhopper.com/public/maps/0.3/". Downloaded the lastest version. Android 4.0+.

Comment: I don't mean the error message I mean the logs + exception. Would be very appreciated as I don't have such a device + error.

Comment: We've found another bug, please see here and try and report back :) https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/127#issuecomment-39086951